# Node js Segmentation fault on Https server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I try to configure my node server to SSL, my node server and php both work on the same instance. node is start without error but when i send a request though the socket or web url, it will crashed. only show 
**segmentation Fault**

my node version is 6.9.4

here my Node js script

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('express')();


var f_root = 'path_to_ssl';
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(f_root+'ssl.myserver.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(f_root+'ssl.myserver.pem')
};

app.get("/", function(request, response){
    console.log(" Hello World");

});

var httpsserver = https.createServer(options, app);


httpsserver.listen(3001);
```

Comment: Can you please paste the error exactly as it is displayed?

Comment: also, you are calling `https.createServer` twice, but assigning it to two different variables.  Your `httpserver` variable should have the `http.createServer` assignment

Comment: "Segmentation fault"  that all

Comment: you are also missing a semicolon at the end of the `httpserver.listen(8080)` line.

Comment: " you are also missing a semicolon at the end of the " i fixed it. but still get the error.. the error happen only when i send a request to the server.. it work fine in http

Comment: fix the `https.createServer` duplication problem and see if you still have the same issue.  You need the line `var httpserver = http.createServer(app);`

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527939/create-run-secure-https-nodejs-express-app-with-self-signed-certificates-s

Comment: " fix the https.createServer " done Still got the issue

Comment: First, update your post above to reflect the changes you've made in your code.  Second, the other post that had the same problem (link above) seems to indicate this might be related to how your keys were created.  The poster had the same problem but then generated the keys using a different script and it seemed to work...

Comment: don't use node.js and php at the same time. They don't like to work together. Use one of both, node or php.

Comment: Update the code. Server is running under nginx platform, php and node both are running under same domain.  https is work fine for the php

Comment: @KingReload may be on to something, you may have conflicts between PHP and node.js if they are running on the same domain on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue

issue was the .pem file. i use the .crt instead of .pem file

here the update

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('express')();


var f_root = 'path_to_ssl';
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(f_root+'ssl.myserver.key'),
    // this is the issue
    cert: fs.readFileSync(f_root+'ssl.myserver.crt')
};

app.get("/", function(request, response){
    console.log(" Hello World");

});

var httpsserver = https.createServer(options, app);


httpsserver.listen(3001);
```